# Salesforce 1.4.1 with Sitecore 8.1

Tags: salesforce-connect

I am doing a POC, trying to connect Sitecore and Salesforce. I wish to try to configure using Salesforce Connect 1.4.1 with Sitecore 8.1, but I can't find any article or documentation. Can someone help point me to any article or documentation on this?

I did check the documentation below but it's in initial release.

https://github.com/adamconn/sitecore-salesforce-connect

Thanks in advance.

-Arsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of **SalesForce Connect v 1.4.1**  can be found here: http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/SalesforceConnect/v1.4.1/

Your link is not the right one, that's the personal repository of Adam Conn.

If you want to download you can download the module from Sitecore portal: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Salesforce_Connect/Salesforce_Connect_1/Salesforce_Connect_1_4_1.aspx

Installation documentation : https://doc.sitecore.net/crm_connect/141